# change class name with js

Tags: javascript, hyperlink

I have menu list that contains:

```
<ul class="content_menu tabs">
        <a href="#" name="content_1" class="tab active"><li class="pager_link_0_active"></li></a>
        <a href="#" name="content_2" class="tab"> <li class="pager_link_1"></li></a>
        <a href="#" name="content_3" class="tab"><li class="pager_link_2"></li></a>
        <a href="#" name="content_4" class="tab"><li class="pager_link_3"></li></a>
        <a href="#" name="content_5" class="tab"><li class="pager_link_4"></li></a>
        <a href="#" name="content_6" class="tab"><li class="pager_link_5"></li></a>
        <a href="#" name="content_7" class="tab"><li class="pager_link_6"></li></a>
        <a href="#" name="content_8" class="tab"><li class="pager_link_7"></li></a> 
        <a href="#" name="content_9" class="tab"><li class="pager_link_8"></li></a>                                              
</ul>
```

What I want to do is when particular link is clicked I need to remove active from li class name that contains active (e.g pager_link_0_active) and add active to the li that is clicked (e.g pager_link_2_active)

I know there is one way to make it:

`$(".active").removeClass("active");`

`$(this).addClass("active");`

but in my situation, active is not seperated, it is part of class name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to standards ul can contain only element but what you want can be achived these way:

```
        $(function () {
            $('ul.content_menu.tabs a.tab').click(function () {
                var newActive = $(this);

                if (newActive.hasClass('active')) {
                    return;
                }

                var oldActive = $('ul.content_menu.tabs a.tab.active');
                oldActive.removeClass('active');
                var oldIndex = $('ul.content_menu.tabs a.tab').index(oldActive);
                oldActive.children().attr('class', 'pager_link_' + oldIndex);

                var newIndex = $('ul.content_menu.tabs a.tab').index(newActive);
                newActive.addClass('active');
                newActive.children().attr('class', 'pager_link_' + newIndex + '_active');
            });
        });
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qaKxa/)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to make it a separate class `<li class="pager_link_1  pager_active">`, then you can remove and add pager_active easily.

If the LI will always have just one class, try this:

```
var active_li = $(".active li");
var active_class = active_li.attr("class");
active_li.attr("class", active_attr.replace("_active", "");
var this_li = $(this).children("li");
var this_class = this_li.attr("class");
this_li.attr("class", this_class+"_active");
```